# Is a limit point of branch points a branch point?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivalued-functions, branch-points

I have come into a discussion with my friends over a complex analysis question:

Is $\infty$ a branch point of $\log(\cos z)$?

I can't get a clear answer to this from the definition of branch points. Maybe it's because I've only learnt about primary complex analysis which defines branch point as 'a point which, if you run $z$ through any contour around it, would change the value of $f(z)$'.

Since $\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi ,\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$ are branch points of $f(z)=\log(\cos z)$, $\infty$ is a limit point of branch points. Follow the above definition, it seems that any contour around $\infty$ would change the value of $f(z)$, but it also seems that this should be the credit of the finite branch points. So, based on rigid definitions, is $\infty$ a branch point of $f(z)=\log(\cos z)$?(Equivalently, is $0$ a branch point of $\log(\cos\frac{1}{z})$?)

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a branch point is an isolated singularity of a multivalued analytic function.  That is, for $z_0$ to be a branch point of $f$, there must be a deleted neighbourhood $U$ of $z_0$ such that for each $z \in U$, each branch of $f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $z$.  So no,  $\infty$ is not a branch point of $\log(\cos(z))$.

Comment: Do you have any citation for this 'definition'? Our textbook actually states that a branch point is always a non-isolated singularity since the function's derivative isn't well defined on the branch cut and there are infinitely many points on the branch cut in the branch point's neighborhood.

Comment: I don't understand, why do you say, a branch point is a isolated singularity?

Comment: Is it not true that, all points on branch cut carry discontinuity? So, how do one say then a branch point is a isolated singularity?

Comment: Is this statement "$\text{all points on branch cut carry discontinuity}$" always not true? Please sir, I do wanna know it.

Comment: There is no single-valued branch of the function that is continuous in a deleted neighbourhood of the branch point, but the multivalued function will be continuous in a deleted neighbourhood.

Comment: See e.g. [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Branch_point).

Comment: Thank you, sir! And,also, one question, is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ branch cut of $\log(\cos z)$?

Comment: If you take the branch of log that has a branch cut on $[0,\infty)$, $\log(\cos z)$ will have branch cuts  $[(2n-1/2)\pi,(2n+1/2)\pi]$ for all integers $n$.